# Check for trailing backslah

Tags: c#

I want to check if the trailing backslash exists on a path. which is a good practice?

1. Using Path.combine
2. Checking slash manually by using EndsWith function

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your problem? `Path.Combine` _probably_ use some string operations as well. Using `EndsWith` is fine if I understand your question clearly.

Comment: Just to be clear, the string `http://www.google.com` would return false, but `http://www.google.com/` would return true?

Comment: @Equalsk - people usually mean `\\` when they say "backslash"

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I meant `\\` not the other way around. Need more coffee...

Comment: Is the question asking which of the two way is better?

Comment: Yes I am asking which of the two ways is better? Any disadvantages?

Comment: I don't believe Path.Combine removes trailing slashes, unless there's some overload I'm missing. So surely you wants EndsWith followed by whatever logic to deal with that slash.

Comment: `EndsWith` for sure. But note that it's also possible to use forward slashes as a path separator, so watch out for that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any further context to your question this is as much information as I can provide.

> [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   Combines strings into a path.

Example:

```
string path1 = @"C:\test";
string path2 = @"I have\a trailing slash\";
string path3 = Path.Combine(path1, path2);
```

path3 is now `C:\test\I have\a trailing slash\`

**As you can see, the trailing slash has not been removed.**

---

> [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   Determines whether the end of this string instance matches a specified string.

Example:

```
string path1 = @"C:\test\I have\a trailing slash\";
bool hasSlash = path1.EndsWith(@"\");
```

hasSlash is now equal to `true`.

---

**Conclusion**

For your specific purposes, `EndsWith` is the correct function to use here followed by whatever logic you need to deal with that slash.